# Following a recent upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 installation terminal prompt is only displaying 4 characters

Tags: prompt

Have attempted fix using fonts in tweaks but that also only displays 4 characters for any font name and does not fix problem. Have tried installing alternative desktop and running several different terminals with no change.

Comment: There are a tons of this reported, search for "4 letters" or something, sorted by newest. It seems to be related to either `oibaf/graphics-drivers` PPA or some MESA graphics drivers. Maybe they are one and the same thing... Some people talked about puriging, some about downgrading. I have not seen a complete answer yet that would demonstrate the specific commands needed for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Really the problem is with oibaf/graphics-drivers, after remove and reinstalled gnome-shell it returned to normal.

`sudo apt install ppa-purge;sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa -y`

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y`

This will remove all oibaf drivers, then reinstall gnome-shell

`sudo apt install gnome-shell -y`