# Irregular and broken fonts in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, system

Why Fonts are irregular and broken in xubuntu whether it's in the menu bar, file manager, terminal and others

[image]

Comment: It's because your graphics driver, probably from the oibaf:graphics-drivers PPA got a faulty update, that you need to undo somehow. There was an onpour of these issues here on AskUbuntu last week. Some of the questions got apparently working answers.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: I don't know for sure because I did not have this issue. But here are two where an answer at least got an upvote: https://askubuntu.com/q/1328152/1157519 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1329451/1157519

Comment: Thanks is worked for me