# Ubuntu 20.04 - Mate desktop went wacko

Tags: mate

### Drive was full, so I cleaned it up and provided more room. As a result, lost this version of Mate and the version I'm using now, doesn't have the problem so I'm good.

**Original post...**

I don't really know how to describe this issue. It just popped up a while ago and I don't recall what might have triggered it. Just seemed to happen.

[image: Funny fonts?]

I'm perplexed. When I open a browser, that looks fine, so I did a search stumbling on what exactly to call the problem. I found a thread that might be it and I think reinstalled Mate's desktop using a crippled Term because it's affected too. I'm used to how it behaves so I could work with it. But after reboot the software install didn't seem to cure anything.

I seem to remember this from a few years ago but can't remember the fix.

Anyone?

Comment: When you edit your question with a better screenshot, please include more details about the exact steps/commands you used when you attempted to fix the problem. A more detailed description of the problem would also be helpful.  Please also tell us any changes made to your device that corresponded with the first appearance of the problem. ex: updates, new software, commands you put in the terminal, etc

Comment: I'll have to boot into my other drive to get the command I used. BBL.

Comment: I noticed you uploaded a clearer screenshot.  This might be an issue with fonts used by the UI. Were there any fonts added, removed, or changed, or did you make any manual changes to configuration files related to the desktop environment or UI?

Comment: I think I know what it is...the HDD is stuffed full. There's that warning box in the middle of the screen shot that I could not read initially but I think I got the gist of it now. It's telling me there's no more room on the drive. So I'll have to fix that first. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: No time wasted! I'm here to help. If the root file system is full it can create all sorts of problems because essential writes can't be written to the drive when it is full.

Comment: Many, many similar issues have been reported recently here, without answers thus far. Include info on the graphics card in your post: `sudo lshw -c display`

Comment: Right, look here someone got happy today: https://askubuntu.com/q/1333267/1157519 (It's not about Mate or Gnome or XFCE, neither about what you did; it's about a faulty graphics driver update.)

Answer (score 1):

From OP's comments:

> I think I know what it is...the HDD is stuffed full. There's that warning box in the middle of the screen shot that I could not read initially but I think I got the gist of it now. It's telling me there's no more room on the drive. So I'll have to fix that first. Sorry to waste your time.